# Sorting a ruby array ignoring case

Tags: ruby

I know there are examples on Stackoverflow solving a similar problem but I could not make any of the approaches work. I'm constructing an array for a grouped collection select. The approach below partially works until it comes across a lowercase name. I know that &:downcase can be used in these situations but I can't figure out how to apply it in the case below. Any help is appreciated.

```
<% myprojects = Project.having_production_stages.sort_by(&:formal_name)  %>
```

Comment: You should definitely learn what `&:` is doing. It's shorthand for a specific case of a more general concept that will be really useful for you in solving similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say you're using `mysql` and `Project.having_production_stages` returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, this should be the best way to go

```
Project.having_production_stages.order('LOWER(formal_name)')
```

If it's not a relation but simply a collection try

```
Project.having_production_stages.sort_by { |project| project.formal_name.downcase }
```

Comment: My pleasure. ;)